# extracting names out of a string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

First, the purpose is to distinguish only names from a string that is consist of Korean names, English names, special characters (-,*,comma), whitespaces, etc. and to leave only one if a name is duplicated.

So, what I've done so far is I've taken a text file and converted it into a string, eliminating unnecessary special characters.

```
import re

path = 'E:\Data Science\Personal_Project\Church\Data\original.txt'

def open_text(path):
    with open(path, "r", encoding='euc-kr') as f:
        text = f.readlines()
        string = ''.join(text)
        unicode_line = string.translate({ord(c): None for c in '.;*\n'})
        cleaned = re.split('-|', unicode_line)


print(unicode_line, type(cleaned))
return(cleaned)
```

Here's the question. What I want to add to Function above

1) If there's a letter in front of a dashed line (e.g., "Attendance ---"), I want to remove the text in front of it (e.i., "Attendance") before splits it on dashes.

2) Or I'd like to make a list -- [Attendance, Check-Out, Vacation] -- and I'd like to remove the words that are included in the list.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me a better way or a more pythonic way of doing it!!

For your convenience, I'll add a sample text.

```
Status of January 20th




** Attendance
-----------

John Smith, John Smith, Bob Smith, Mike Smith, Jane Jones, Daniel Lee, Dong Jones, Jeannie Jones, Jessica Yi, McAleer Chung, Shu K Smith, Song Kim, Steve Carlos, Bob Smith





** Absent
---------

holiday, unauthorized, unpaid leave, emergency
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Brown Williams, Paul Garcia
```

Also, here is my desired output with only unduplicated names. If you see above, there are two John Smith and two Bob Smith. Lastly, it will be awesome if I can get it in Alphabetical order.

```
Output:


John Smith, Bob Smith, Mike Smith, Jane Jones, Daniel Lee, Dong Jones, Jeannie Jones, Jessica Yi, McAleer Chung, Shu K Smith, Song Kim, Steve Carlos, Brown Williams, Paul Garcia
```

Comment: Not really clear. Can you show some example output for that file? Also, I think just joining all lines and removing `\n` will make things harder for you.

Comment: @tobias_k I added my desired output! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the `set` of all the names in the document, without the words in certain header lines and without words in a predefined list of non-name-words, like "vacation".

First, I'd suggest not joining all the lines, then you can e.g. check whether a line starts with `-` or `*` and exclude that line. It also makes it easier to skip the first line with the header. Then, you can just define your list of non-name-words, loop over the lines in the file and split by `,`.

```
non_names = set("holiday, unauthorized, unpaid leave, emergency".split(", "))
with open("text.txt") as f:
    next(f) # skip first line
    names = set()
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith(("*", "-")):
            for name in line.strip().split(", "):
                if name and name not in non_names:
                    names.add(name)
```

Or using `set` directly on a complex generator expression:

```
    names = set(name for line in f
                     if not line.startswith(("*", "-"))
                     for name in line.strip().split(", ")
                     if name and name not in non_names)
```

Both ways, the result is `{'John Smith', 'Jeannie Jones', 'Mike Smith', 'Bob Smith', 'McAleer Chung', 'Steve Carlos', 'Brown Williams', 'Jessica Yi', 'Paul Garcia', 'Jane Jones', 'Shu K Smith', 'Song Kim', 'Daniel Lee', 'Dong Jones'}`. To get sorted names, just sort the `set`, or if you want to sort by the last name, use a special `key` function:

```
names = sorted(names, key=lambda s: s.split()[-1])
```

Comment: thank you, I can clearly understand what you are explaining.

If a string goes like "non-name-name" i.e "school-James Harden" there is no space between school and dashed line and James. How should I get only James Harden from it? I think I can add one more delimeter when you line.strip().split(", ")

Comment: @YunTaeHwang You probably could just split by `-` also, but then what about names that contain a `-`? Those are not uncommon. Might be better to only strip those from the beginning of the lines using some regex (assuming they can only occur in the beginning). You could try `for name in re.sub("^[a-z]+-", "", line.strip()).split(", ")`

Answer (score 1):

Potential solution:

Presuming the format of the file is as you've given
Go through the file line by line
Ignore all lines where the first and second word are not capitalized
Then process that line as a name list

```
for line in file:
  words = line.split(",")

  #No one has just one name like Tupac
  if len(words) > 1:
    #Check to see if first letter of both words are uppercase
    if isUpper(words[0][0]) and isUpper(words[1][0]):
      #name line
      list_to_be_returned+=words
```

Something like that maybe

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filename)as file:
    words = file.read().split()
```

also you can use regex

```
import re

with open(filename)as file:
    words = re.findall(r'([\w]+)', file.read())
```

Comment: Isn't this kind of incomplete? You just get a list of words; you neither filter out the non-name parts, nor do you now which words are part of the same name.